# Hardware Virtualization in Asus 1215n Netbook

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, netbook, vt-x

Is it possible to enable Hardware Virtualization on the Asus 1215n netbook?  I know the Intel Atom CPU supports it but I can't find an option for it in the BIOS.

I am trying to run different Operating Systems in VMWare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Asus site specs](http://ca.asus.com/en/Eee/Eee_PC/Eee_PC_1215N/#specifications), the 1215n contains an Atom D525.

[image: AsusSiteShot]

[According to Intel](http://ark.intel.com/products/49490), the Atom D525 does *NOT* support Virtualization.

[image: IntelSiteShot]

Answer (score 0):

See [this link](http://www.intel.com/support/processors/sb/cs-030729.htm) from Intel. They will tell you if your processor supports virtualization